Elementor time field using flatpickr related issue
I want to edit the functionality of time field, availabel in elementor pro form, i wnat when user select a date from date field, if today's date is selected then in time field user can only select the time perirod after current time, from date field if other date is selected then user can select the time between 10 am to 6pm. (if today date is selected, and current time is 2 pm then from time field user can only select the time after 2 pm to 6 pm).
I have written a plan javascript code in which works, but when i apply it to elementor using related field id then its not working, any help could be appereciated.
Plane javascript code:
